# How to shutdown flask server?

Tags: python, flask

I've tried using signals, keystroke logging, multiprocessing to shutdown the servers but am not having any luck. I want this flask app to run, return the code from the redirect_uri and then exit the server and continue with the main flow. Here is what I have so far.

```
import webbrowser
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

server = Process
code = ''
client_id = "4325234352342324"
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:80/shutdown"


@app.route('/')
def data():
    data = request.args
    return data

@app.after_request
def write_file():
    code = request.args['code']
    f = open('code.txt', 'w')
    f.write(code)

@app.before_first_request
def before_request():
    webbrowser.open(f"https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code")

@app.route('/shutdown')
def server_shutdown():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=80)
```

Comment: Usually web servers are long-running. If you want to make a few requests only, consider something like the `requests` package; if you need a web server, you probably don't want to shut it down

Comment: Hm I did try a GET request, following the GitHub Authorization web application flow. I'm wondering how I can parse the code that is appended to the URL after redirection from the first endpoint (OAuth authorization and login). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the github API documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api. This includes notes on authenticating and probably reading/writing from a repo using a package like `requests`.  This will be easier than using endpoints designed for human interaction (e.g. `https://github.com/login`)

Comment: @anon01 why wouldnt you want it to shutdown if you only need it to authenticate users just the first time to get a code with e.g. pkce. There's no way to do that with requests

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried the shutdown server with an outdated option (I'm talking about the `server_shutdown` function). So, `werkzeug.server.shutdown` is deprecated after [this patch](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/1873). For now, it's better to do it as described in the [Werkzeug documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/serving/#shutting-down-the-server). There, of course, there is no flask app, but it is not difficult to change the code to suit your needs. I also found that a [similar question](https://github.com/pallets/flask/discussions/4218) was asked in the Flask github discussions that should help you too.

UPD [03.07.2022]

Okay, the bot says that I could add something, but it is unlikely that any materials like articles or documentation are needed, because I have added all the sources of information that may be useful to the one who asked the question and those that I used to solve this issue. So I decided to add some code. Here it is:

```py
import multiprocessing
from flask import Flask, request

def github_oauth(q: multiprocessing.Queue) -> None:
    app = Flask(...)
    # here you describe your endpoint(s)
    app.run('localhost', 80)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=github_oauth, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print("waiting")
    code = q.get(block=True)
    p.terminate()
    print(code)
    # do something else...
```

Thus, you only need to write the logic of the flask application correctly. When you do this, you will be able to make a single request through `requests` library or through the browser or something else, and then continue to do something in the main flow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any comments about this?